# Text widgets: is there a yscrollincrement and can content geometry be queried?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Does the text widget have anything similar to the yscrollincrement of a canvas, such that the scrolling unit can be something other than a full line, such that when an image or another widget is embedded the scrolling won't jump the height of the widget but a normal line height?

Also, is it possible to query the geometry of the text widget's content rather than its screen size?  For example, suppose I read data in from a database and then display it in a text widget and want to set the height of the widget to the content height to start. Perhaps, it's obvious and I'm just overlooking it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [text widgets](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.html) (assuming you have a new enough version of Tk) the scroll increments are pre-determined as being the *visual* line and the *visual* page. This isn't necessarily the logical line, due to the possibility of font changes and line wrapping (which turns logical lines into paragraphs). The computation of the line heights to support this is complex and expensive, and will be done in the background if lots of data is loaded at once. Once the line geometry calculations are complete, you get fully smooth scrolling when dragging the scrollbar and it remains a constant length.

I can't remember now whether it was Tk 8.5 or 8.6 where the behaviour changed to work this way. I *think* it was 8.6, but I really wouldn't swear to it.  If you're using a version where what I say appears not true, upgrading is the sole recommended fix, *especially for new code!*

For your other question, have a look at the `bbox` and `dlineinfo` methods, paying particular attention to the forms that an index may take. For example, the top-left visual character has a bounding box given by `$txt bbox @0,0`, and the related measurements for the visual line are given by `$txt dlineinfo @0,0`. However, it's probably a bad idea to try to set a text widget to the height of data loaded; it tends to be better to give it a fixed height, load in variable height data, and then let the widget handle all the scrolling and windowing. You can give it a hint where to include within the viewport via the `see` method (you'd probably give it logical coordinates; using display coords is… unlikely to make much useful sense as you can see those already).

Comment: Thank you.  I have Tk 8.6.11. The text widget scrolls smoothly when drag the slider as you described.  The arrow buttons scroll a line each time, but when a widget or image is embedded I think the height of the line is set to the widget height and scrolling jumps the full widget.  I'd like it to scroll the same amount all the time.  I noticed also that if the content is all text and scroll using an arrow button, the slider changes its height as the widget scrolls, sort of like an inch worm. That doesn't happen when drag the slider. Is that expected or an indication of an error in my code?

Comment: That inch-worm thing is there only when the slider is fairly small, perhaps its due to some type of rounding to integer pixels. I don't see it when the slider height is a couple inches.